# How to configure the proxy to bypass modification for error responses (e.g., responses with status codes other than 200) in NX package?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, http-proxy

I'm using [nx monorepo](https://nx.dev/packages/express#application-proxies) . I have a proxy which working, however when I try to send status with error message it does not display the error in the fetched result. How can I change the proxy in order to return the error too.
Here is the proxy setting:

```
  "/api/v1/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
```

This is how I send the error from express to the client:

```
res.status(401).send(error)
```

And here is the response I receive from the front end:

```
type: "basic", 
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users", 
redirected: false, 
status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", 
headers: Headers(7), 
body: ReadableStream {locked:false}, bodyUsed: false }​
```

[image]

This is how I fetch in the frontend :

```
        fetch("/api/v1/users", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            }
        })
```

Comment: I dont see a problem, how do you fetch the API from the client?

Comment: @Marc in this way:
        fetch("/api/v1/users", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            }
        })
I know the fetch in the frontend works because when I don't get an error it shows me the users

Comment: You dont do anything with the request. e.g. convert it via `.then((req) => req.json();`

Comment: @Marc when the fetch returns an error from the server ( res.status(401).send(error) ), the .then does not work, it is handled in the catch function. My problem is that I can't get the custom error that I send from the server, the proxy, I believe it changes. I don't know how to show my error that I send from server. I use a package called nx which is a monorepo. It handles the proxy itself but I don't know how can make the custom error displayed.